# Fix "WiFi Disabled by hardware switch" in Kubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, kubuntu, toshiba-satellite, wifi-hardware-switch

Any ideas on how to fix this? My Toshiba Satellite Click doesn't have a hardware switch to disable wireless. Help!!

Answer (score 2):

I got the same problem.I did

```
Restart -> F2 -> Bios settings -> Reset bios to default -> save
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

First try to unblock in Ubuntu with:

```
rfkill unblock all
```

If this doesn't work read on.

## If you are dual-booting with Windows.

Boot Windows, enable wifi and reboot.
In my system, if I disable wifi in Windows, I'm not able to unblock it in Ubuntu. Ubuntu is able to remove the soft block but not the hard block on my system.

Comment: The sad part is I'm not dual booting and rfkill doesn't work..

Comment: Try going in Bios settings. There is a wi-fi communications setting. Check if it is on.

Comment: The only thing that has an enable or disable switch is the web camera. Nothing about networking at all

Comment: Does your Toshiba have a physical Wifi switch?

Comment: Nope, everything is internal. Its their satellite 'Click' series. The 2 -in1 's

Comment: The extreme solution is to find a Windows disc (or download one) and unblock the wifi. You could then burn a DVD, launch the installer and maybe before it starts copying files, you will hav the opportunity to unblock the wifi.

Comment: How do i boot a windows install disc if i have GRUB installed over Windows Boot Manager??

Comment: I figured it out! Reinstalled windows and the wireless driver, then proceeded to reinstall ubuntu. Eureka! Wireless is back online!!

Comment: It's sad that Ubuntu cannot unblock hard blocked Wi-fi while Windows can.

Comment: I know! I wouldn't have gotten myself into this big of a problem if it could. Whatever though, everything got resolved!

Answer (score 0):

I searched for some images, and all of them had a little button in the top row containing a networking image (see here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/yeeh7qry8ypzbi4/toshiba_satellite_l850150.jpg?dl=0). I am pretty sure that that button is your hardware switch.

Comment: Thats not the right one. I have the toshiba satellite w35dt-a3300 click series

Answer (score 0):

Is it toshiba-laptop or toshiba-wmi that's loaded? Find out with:

```
$ lsmod | grep toshiba
```

Remove whichever is loaded, like this:
For Example:

```
$ sudo rmmod -f toshiba-laptop
$ sudo rfkill unblock all
$ rfkill list all
```

This solution works for mine.